# ParseException when using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying the following code and I keep getting the exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-11-05T16:24:55+02:00"

My code goes as the following:

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
date = formatter.parse(dateValue);
```

My Date Input is:

> 2015-11-05T16:24:55+02:00

and I would like to translate it to:

> 05-11-2015 T16:24:55+02:00

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Java 7+ you can simply replace the `Z` by an `X`. More information about the difference between `Z` (RFC822) and `X` (ISO 8601) is available in [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

If you are on Java 6 or earlier, you will need to remove the `:` in the original string, something like:

```
date = formatter.parse(dateValue.replaceAll(":(\\d+)$", "$1"));
```